# Can I switch between tabs with custom keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am trying to find a way to navigate between tabs with custom keyboard shortcuts. For example, if I have 4 tabs opened, I want KEY+1 for the first tab, KEY+2 for the 2nd, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Such key bindings are defined within each application individually. If you can switch between tabs with custom keyboard shortcuts or not depends on whether the application exposes a way to assign or change keybindings,

At least Files, Text Editor (gedit) and the browsers Firefox and Chromium have some predefined keybindings that resemble what you are looking for. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> to move to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd tab. These applications, however, do not expose ways to change these keyboard shortcuts.